# Removing material from project

Tags: materials, linked-data

Despite several answers to this same question, I have been unable to successfully remove a material from the materials list in my projects. Following answers in other questions, I have gone to the Properties section and opened the materials tab, then selected the material I want to remove, then clicked the X button next to the list to unlink. I've also tried this with a shift click to set the users to zero. After a save and reload, the material is still in the list.

Since I believe I've followed the instructions in multiple answers to the letter, I am forced to conclude that there is something different about my project. The material is a direct linked library datablock. Perhaps this is the cause? If so, I'm guessing I need to remove the link between the external file and this project.

Another answer suggested to click the make local button next to the list, but this seems to create a local copy of the material, while the original remains linked. The local copy can be removed following the standard methods, however.

Comment: As a linked item, the object using the material will replace it when you re-open. You will need to remove the material from the model in the external file. The make local option would need to be applied to the object using the material not the material.

Comment: Care to post the .blend using [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

To remove a material from your file, go to the materials tab and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> the × next to the material.

The material will be set to 0 uses. Consequently, saving your project, closing and reopening it will remove it from the list of available materials.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your outliner and select "Blend File" from the drop-down.  Expand the list of materials, find the one you want gone, right-click it, and delete.  It will immediately completely remove the material from the file.

Answer (score -1):

When you delete the material you have to click the X beside it holding the SHIFT button.

Comment: I did. Does not work.