# Delete material from »browse material to be linked« dropdown

Tags: materials

I use Blender 2.9.3. But one thing which I want to ask since years is how can I delete a Material from the »browse material to be linked« dropdown?

[image]

Comment: This is all (non-grease pencil)  materials in blend   Question could be: "how to delete a material"   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72675/removing-material-from-project

Comment: [https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219380/is-there-an-easy-way-to-detect-unused-material-slots-in-an-object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219380/is-there-an-easy-way-to-detect-unused-material-slots-in-an-object)

Comment: Sorry for that question! But if I search fro delete materials I got not exactly what I want. Also the answer from @JohnEason solves it not completely. After clean up my scene I have a last not used material in the list. And I have proof that it is not connected to a model.

Comment: Does it have a '0' in front of the name of the material in the list? If so it isn't used and should disappear if you save the blend file and close Blender. Load the file again and it should have disappeared.

Comment: .. or Purge Orphan Data https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121531/how-do-i-delete-unused-data